# Do I need to implement the DrawerItemClickListener class in each activity?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Currently, I'm cloning this code snippet in each activity to get the same Navigation Bar on the left side. Obviously, that involves tedious edits if I change anything and I have to edit all instances of that. So I'm sure there is a smarter way to do this i.e. have a single location and just reference that in each activity ?

```html
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch(position) {

                case 0:

                    Intent intentMain = new Intent(CardView.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentMain);

                    break;

                case 1:

                    Intent intentFront = new Intent(CardView.this, FrontPage.class);
                    startActivity(intentFront);

                    break;
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...
```

Comment: Yeah, OOP basics like inheritance - common base class which contains common stuff implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate file with your DrawerItemClickListener class and than create an instance in each activity.

```
public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener 
{
    private Activity mActivity;
    public DrawerItemClickListener(Activity activity) {
       mActivity = activity;
    }        

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch(position) {

            case 0:

                Intent intentMain = new Intent(mActivity, MainActivity.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(intentMain);

                break;

            case 1:

                Intent intentFront = new Intent(mActivity, FrontPage.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(intentFront);

                break;
             ...
             ...
             ...
```

And in activity:

```
mDrawerItemClickListener  = new DrawerItemClickListener(this)
```

Comment: oh, you can treat it like any other Java class ? I thought it required special treatment, d'oh, seems obvious now, thanks for the detailed answer (editing my code), saved me some headaches with the activity handling.